# Problem with ecrecover, it returns an incorrect address

Tags: solidity, hardhat, signature, ecrecover

I know that this issue is already in other questions but I've already read them and they didn't help.
I'm trying to sign a message in my tests, I'm using hardhat and this is the code I'm using to sign the message:

```
async function signPreorder(idItem: number, contractAddress: string, nonce: number) {
        const accounts = await ethers.getSigners();

        const hash = "0x" + abi.soliditySHA3(
            ['uint256', 'address', 'uint256'],
            [idItem, contractAddress, nonce]
        );
        const signature = await accounts[0].signMessage(hash);
        return {
            r: signature.slice(0, 66),
            s: '0x' + signature.slice(66, 130),
            v: '0x' + signature.slice(130, 132)
        }
    }
```

Then there's the function of my contract that should check who signed the message:

```
function preorderItem(
        uint256 _idItem,
        uint256 _nonce,
        uint8 _v,
        bytes32 _r,
        bytes32 _s
    ) external view returns (address, address) {
        bytes32 message = keccak256(
            abi.encodePacked(_idItem, address(this), _nonce)
        );
       
        return (ecrecover(message, _v, _r, _s), owner());
    }
```

I'm calling the function like this:

```
const { r, s, v } = await signPreorder(0, marketplace.address, 1);

            const value = await marketplace.preorderItem(
                0,
                1,
                v,
                r,
                s
            );
```

The smart contract function returns

```
[
  '0x3Ce3c743d2F7aF2A8BA8E1a681a743994B6D18a8',
  '0xf39Fd6e51aad88F6F4ce6aB8827279cffFb92266'
]
```

So those two are not the same addresses, I would expect to find the same address.

What am I doing wrong?
Thanks.

Comment: This type of problems are very nasty to figure out, since all you get is incorrect address and no idea why. I suggest you check some ready libraries for signatures, such as https://github.com/BestItPartner/nft_lazy_minting/blob/main/lib/LazyMinter.js or https://www.npmjs.com/package/eth-permit

Comment: The only way is that `accounts[0]` in hardhat and `owner()` in solidity are different. Since ecrecover returned something that isn't zero, it means that it worked

Comment: @0xSanson you were right. Yesterday I found the error and it was something similar to what you suggested. Thank you very much to both of you